# Grafana and InfluxDB alert issue

Tags: influxdb, grafana-alerts

We are trying to create grafana alert using InfluxDB connection. In the alert rule we are getting only numeric values data but we are unable to fetch character/string values(getting null data).

In grafana panel we are getting all types of data, only we have issue in alert rule using influxdb connection.

do we have any solution for it??

We are expecting a way to fetch character values in grafana alert rules.
[grafana results:[conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAdTS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVjjJ.png)